# mysql timestampdiff always returning null?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am using version 14.4 of mysql and I am trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MINUTE(NOW()), NOW())
```

This should return a timestamp that is on the current hour, but it's always returning null. `TIMESTAMPADD` works just fine, I am only having trouble with this function. I have looked for answers to this problem through google and mysql documentation but I couldn't find anything.

Does anyone have any an idea on what's going wrong?

My full goal is a query that returns how many minutes are left from now until 5 of the next hour. For example. If its 1:30, our target time is 1:55, so the query would return 25

Comment: You want the difference in minutes between NOW and NOW??

Comment: I'm also fairly certain that "version 14.4" refers to something other than your MySQL version.

Comment: That query produces `error 1292: Incorrect datetime value`, and refers to the second parameter.  The function spec is TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the hour

```
SELECT CURTIME()
```

That query you posted is absurd,or be more clear about what you want.

Comment: Why is it absurd? Let me tell you my full goal. My full goal is a query that returns how many minutes are left from now until 5 of the next hour. For example. If its 1:30, our target time is 1:55, so the query would return 25

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to floor the current UNIX timestamp to the current hour?  If so, why not be explicit about it?

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() % 3600;`

Based on your edits, you can also calculate the difference to the 5 minute mark preceding the next hour as follows:

```
SELECT MINUTE( TIMEDIFF( 
    NOW(), 
    FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() % 3600 + 3600 - 5*60 )
) );
```

This is just a proof-of-concept query; I haven't yet accounted for rounding the current time to the minute (because I don't know if you want to go up or down), nor handled the edge case where the current time is within 5 minutes of the next hour already (e.g. 1:59).

Comment: My full goal is a query that returns how many minutes are left from now until 5 of the next hour. For example. If its 1:30, our target time is 1:55, so the query would return 25, so there is a little more than i originally said

Comment: You mean until 5 minutes before the start of the next hour? What would happen if it's 1:55? 1:59?

Comment: That is a good point. I can work around that with a case statement. I really dont understand why my original query returns null. If I did something like

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 5, NOW())

It would work just fine, only doesnt work if I have a query in the middle

Comment: @yemista: as I indicated in an earlier comment to your question, the [function spec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) for TIMESTAMPDIFF is not the same as TIMESTAMPADD.